# Update Oracle SQL - table with values from duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

i hope that somebody could help. I need to update a table from a select with duplicates.

[image: table with duplicates]

```
ID;CLASS;VALUE;NEW
1;a;a3;
1;b;s6;
1;c;b99;
2;a;s3;
2;b;r6;
2;c;b99;
3;a;s5;
4;a;r6;
4;b;a3;
```

Look at my example table, there is a colum **NEW** which i have to update. In the example the column **NEW** was filled manually.

**Here is the goal (as shown in table col NEW):**

1.find duplicates via ID (HAVING COUNT(*) >1 or something like that)

2. UPDATE TABLE SET NEW=
   CLASS || '_' || VALUE 
   WHERE CLASS='a' or 'b'

Easy for you?

Thx in advance

Comment: Edit your question and provide the results you want.

Comment: Please post data as formatted text, not images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic behind is not completely clear; this could be a way.

setup:

```
create table yourTable(id, class, value, new) as
(
    select 1, 'a', 'a3', cast (null as varchar2(10)) from dual union all
    select 1, 'b', 's6', null from dual union all
    select 1, 'c', 'b99', null from dual union all
    select 2, 'a', 's3', null from dual union all
    select 2, 'b', 'r6', null from dual union all
    select 2, 'c', 'b99', null from dual union all
    select 3, 'a', 's5', null from dual union all
    select 4, 'a', 'r6', null from dual union all
    select 4, 'b', 'a3', null from dual
)
```

query:

```
merge into yourTable t1
using (
        select listagg(value, '_') within group (order by class) as new,
               id      
        from yourTable
        where class in ('a', 'b')
        group by id
        having count(distinct class) = 2
      ) t2
on (    t1.id = t2.id
    and t1.class in ('a', 'b')
   )
when matched then
update set t1.new = t2.new
```

result:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from yourTable;

        ID C VAL NEW
---------- - --- ----------
         1 a a3  a3_s6
         1 b s6  a3_s6
         1 c b99
         2 a s3  s3_r6
         2 b r6  s3_r6
         2 c b99
         3 a s5
         4 a r6  r6_a3
         4 b a3  r6_a3

9 rows selected.
```

Comment: dear Alekseij, this looks good. i will test it and give you a feddback as asap.

Comment: It works! Wow, i didn't know the listagg function, till now. Thanks a lot!